# Renaming content_script stops it from running in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my manifest.json I have:

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["js/punycode.js", "js/content-main.js"]
    }
  ],
```

However if I rename the `content-main.js` to `content-main1.js` update the `manifest.json` to reflect the change (`"js/content-main1.js"`) and reload the extension the script no longer runs.

How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

The Reload Extensions extension that I was using wasn't reflecting the changes in the directory.